# How to make a component (popup modal) appear only once using React hooks or otherwise (React/Next js)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, next.js

I want to make a popup modal appear only once per visit (I don't want it to appear every time someone goes back to the index page). Is there a way to do this using hooks or is there a better method?

```
 export default function Popup() {
        const [visible, setVisible] = React.useState(true);

        if(!visible) return null;

        return (
            <div className={styles.popup} onClick={() => setVisible(false)}>
                {/* <div className={styles.popupInner}> */}
                <div className={styles.popupInner}>
                    <div className={styles.buttonContainer}><Button color="danger" className={styles.button}>Okay</Button></div>
                </div>    
                {/* </div> */}
            </div>
        )
    }
```

Comment: i think you should save your modal status in local storage 
then when app mount just check status in local storage to handle your logic

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do with [`localstorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)  and `useEffect` hook

**why localstorage ?**

> You could achieve same result using `useContext` hook. But at the time of refresh.Hooks not hold the previous value.so better use `localstorage` to store the pop status

```
export default function Popup() {
        const [visible, setVisible] = React.useState(false);
        useEffect(()=>{
          let pop_status = localStorage.getItem('pop_status');
          if(!pop_status){
            setVisible(true);
            localStorage.setItem('pop_status',1);
          }
        },[])
        if(!visible) return null;

        return (
            <div className={styles.popup} onClick={() => setVisible(false)}>
                {/* <div className={styles.popupInner}> */}
                <div className={styles.popupInner}>
                    <div className={styles.buttonContainer}><Button color="danger" className={styles.button}>Okay</Button></div>
                </div>    
                {/* </div> */}
            </div>
        )
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
     export default function Popup() {
            const [visible, setVisible] = React.useState(true);

            if(!visible) return null;

            return (
                <div className={styles.popup}>
                <button onClick={() => setVisible(false)}>Click</button>

                    { visible ? <div className={styles.popupInner}> 
                    <div className={styles.popupInner}>
                        <div className={styles.buttonContainer}>
                           <Button color="danger" className={styles.button}>Okay</Button>
                        </div>
                    </div>    
                    </div> : "" }
                </div>
            )
        }
```